# Is Mahabharat War plans available in online?

Tags: mahabharata

I am very interested in mahabharat War detail explanation every single plan can any one know which site it is available?

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise on what you mean by war please. The 6 parvas namely, udyoga, Bhishma, Drona, Karna, Shalya and Souptika give extensive details on the war. Nearly everything is narated right from armies, formations, weapons, plans etc. You can find the English version of them http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/maha/index.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may already know, Mahabharata is generally accepted to comprise of 18 parvas.

Among these 18 parvas, the 5 parvas namely Bhishma, Drona, Karna, Shalya and Souptika give extensive details on the war. Nearly everything is narated right from armies, formations, weapons, plans etc.

Having said that, it is necessary to read the Udyoga parva to understand the preparation of the war and the stri parva to understand the CLAIMED impact of the war.

You can find the English version of them [here](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/maha/index.htm)

Comment: if you find any TELUGU version please post link

Comment: @narasimha You can find Andhra Mahabharatam here: http://ebooks.tirumala.org/Product/?ID=1872

Comment: @sv. It is a translation of Vyasa Bharata to Telugu or is it a writing of another person, any idea?

Comment: It was supposed to be a translation of Vyasa's original MBH but only has about 20-30K verses in it. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andhra_Mahabharatam).

Comment: Thanks :) .. i personally believe abridging the text can lead to loss or modulation of information. Hence posed the query.